# Check html inputs in php if all = 1, redirect

Tags: php, html

So Im new to this and I cant seem so figure out why this is isnt working

I want the php file to redirect me if all the textboxes has the number 1 in them.

This is my code so far:

```
html file:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleIndex.css">
        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="middle">
                <h1>ENTER CODE</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="Code">
                <form action=action.php method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" name="nm1" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" name="nm2" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" name="nm3" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" name="nm4" required>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" name="nm5" required>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" hidden>
                </form>
            </div>
       </body>
  </html>
```

action.php file:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['nm1']) && ($_POST['nm2'] && ($_POST['nm3'] && ($_POST['nm4'] && ($_POST['nm5'] ='1') {
    header("Location: http://www.kr0kk0.tk/mainpage.php")
}
?>
```

Comment: You have mismatched parenthesis in your action.php

Comment: use == instead of =;  $_POST['nm5']  == 1

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: You're missing a semi colon on the header line

Answer (score 0):

What you have done will return true if there are values within, it however doesn't check what values it contains. You are supposed to do:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
        if(($_POST['nm1'] == 1) && ($_POST['nm2'] == 1) && ($_POST['nm3'] == 1) && ($_POST['nm4'] == 1) && ($_POST['nm5'] == 1)) {
            header("Location: http://www.kr0kk0.tk/mainpage.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following php code:-

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['nm1']) && isset($_POST['nm2']) && isset($_POST['nm3']) && isset($_POST['nm4']) && isset($_POST['nm5']) && $_POST['nm1'] == '1' && $_POST['nm2'] == '1' && $_POST['nm3'] == '1' && $_POST['nm4'] == '1' && $_POST['nm5'] == '1') {
    header("Location: http://www.kr0kk0.tk/mainpage.php");
```

}

It checks if all the  text fields are set to 1, and then redirect accordingly.
?>